# What are Central Conics?

Tags: conic-sections

I have read online that there are conic sections with a "centre of symmetry". They have listed ellipse and hyperbola as examples. Why is/isn't the parabola an example for this?

Comment: Perhaps because the parabola has only one axis of symmetry?

Comment: And the ellipse and hyperbola have two axes of symmetry? Yeah ..... probably